# Zerofill for integers, no zerofill for decimals

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I have a correlation matrix plot that looks like this:

[image: matrix 1]

The problem is that I would like to make '1' appear as '1.0' say, and the decimals will not have any trailing zeroes with precision set to 3. I think the solution is in using  `\pgfmathifisint`. But how I incorporate this, I don't know.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,physics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
        \nextgroupplot[
            title=A correlation matrix,
            xlabel=input parameter $\vb{x}$,
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
            xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5},
            ylabel=input parameter $\vb{y}$,
            ytick={5,4,3,2,1},
            yticklabels={1,2,3,4,5},
            point meta min=-1,
            point meta max=1,
            colormap/temp,
            enlargelimits=false,
            axis on top,
        ]
            \addplot[
            matrix plot*,
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={center},
            nodes near coords style={
                font=\small,
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        precision=3
            },
            point meta=explicit,
            ] file {cor_i.txt};;
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The data set used in cor_i.txt:

```
1 1 -0.206
2 1 -0.044
3 1 -0.045
4 1 -0.866
5 1 1.0

1 2 0.227
2 2 0.053
3 2 -0.105
4 2 1.0
5 2 -0.866

1 3 -0.021
2 3 0.012
3 3 1.0
4 3 -0.105
5 3 -0.045

1 4 -0.655
2 4 1.0
3 4 0.012
4 4 0.053
5 4 -0.44

1 5 1.0
2 5 -0.655
3 5 -0.214
4 5 0.23
5 5 -0.206
```

I've tried hard but haven't reached a solution yet. Or is it not possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my problem, which involves modifying `nodes near coords` as

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathifisint{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1,zerofill]{\pgfretval}}
    {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\pgfretval}}%
}
```

And so the output I finally get is:

[image: output]

The full code is thus:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,physics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}]
        \nextgroupplot[
            title=A correlation matrix,
            xlabel=input parameter $\vb{x}$,
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
            xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5},
            ylabel=input parameter $\vb{y}$,
            ytick={1,2,3,4,5},
            yticklabels={1,2,3,4,5},
            point meta min=-1,
            point meta max=1,
            colormap/temp,
            enlargelimits=false,
            axis on top,
        ]
            \addplot[
            matrix plot*,
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathifisint{\pgfplotspointmeta}
          {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1,zerofill]{\pgfretval}}
          {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\pgfretval}}%
},
            nodes near coords align={center},
            nodes near coords style={
                font=\small,
            },
            point meta=explicit,
            ] file {cor_i.txt};;
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good job finding the solution yourself. But you need to add `zerofill` to the last argument as well, otherwise you can get something like the second last column in the first row ;)

Comment: I did mention in the question that there should not be any trailing zeroes, hence I did not add `zerofill`. If you see the given data set there's just 0.23 and not 0.230. So `precision` is not the main point here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with all entries having 3 decimals, you can use `fixed zerofill` along with `precision=3`.

[image]

```
        \addplot[
        matrix plot*,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={center},
        nodes near coords style={
            font=\small,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
    fixed,
    precision=3,
    fixed zerofill
        },
        point meta=explicit,
        ] file {cor_i.txt};
```

Comment: That would make 1 appear as 1.000, not 1.0. I would like integers only to have a zero after decimal point or verbatim as how the data was given.

Comment: I think the question I should be asking instead is how to plot the data exactly as given.